# how does one show extended unicode > 0xFFFF?

Tags: java, unicode

Some fonts i.e. Symbola and Segoe ui Symbols have characters with five digit hex  assignments. I.e the character "mushroom" is `Ox1F344`.

They show up fine in the character picker in excel etc but this code.

```
gr.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI Symbol",Font.PLAIN,12);

gr.drawString(""+(char)Ox1F344+(char)Ox270B,100,100);
```

Gives me a unknown character and a hand rather than a mushroom and hand.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(char)Ox1F344` will overflow, as [`char` is a 16-bit type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1) and `0x1F344` requires more than 16 bits.

In Java, [characters are UTF-16 code units](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.1), not actual Unicode characters. So you need the UTF-16 version of the character, which is `0xD83C 0xDF44`. Then you need to put that in the string:

```
gr.drawString("\uD83C\uDF44\u270B", 100, 100);
// This -------------------^^^^^^ is unrelated, it's the
// second character shown in your question.
```

Comment: Thanks would char arrays work? Or would the same problem arise?

Comment: @King-Ink: Again, `char` is a 16-bit type. It holds UTF-16 code units, not characters. Some characters cannot be held in a single `char`. Whether a `char` array would work (containing two entries, 0xD83C and 0xDF44) depends on whether the thing receiving the `char` array is Unicode-aware and knows to interpret the first value as the beginning of a surrogate pair.

Comment: Additionally, you need a font that contains the character. There are very few such fonts, cf. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f344/fontsupport.htm (which is not comprehensive, as it does not cover very new or specialized fonts). Note that this character may display in the color of the text or as multicolored, depending on font.

Answer (score 1):

```
""+(char)Ox1F344+(char)Ox270B
```

Java's `char`/`String` types are, unfortunately, based around UTF-16 code units, so 0x1F344 overflows the 16-bit `char` datatype and is the same as 0xF344 (an unstandardised code point in the Private Use Area that could appear as anything).

In UTF-16 to encode a characters outside the Basic Multilingual Plane (0–0xFFFF) you have to use two Surrogate (0xD800–0xDFFF) characters. So the `\u`-escaped form of  is `"\uD83C\uDF44"`.

From 1.5 there are new methods to try to hide this from you and deal with real code points, such as the `int[]` constructor:

```
int[] codePoints = {0x1F344, 0x270B};
new String(codePoints, 0, codePoints.length) // == "" == "\uD83C\uDF44\u270B"
```

Comment: How about Character(0x1F344)?

Comment: @King-ink: `Character` is a wrapper for the primitive datatype `char` so it suffers from the same limitations. Java had the misfortune to be developed at the time it was thought that 16 bits was going to be enough, so there are naming artefacts like `char`/`Character` aligning with “UTF-16 code unit” rather than “Unicode code point” which is what corresponds to a ‘character’ in proper Unicode terminology.

Comment: Annoying but your code does does same thing. I will just hide it in a function that doesn't harm my aesthetic. I will call it Char(). Thank you I think your answer helped me most.